Ideal Carrier Thread count using Java Virtual Threads in Kubernetes
I think I have a pretty good understanding of how Java's Virtual Threads are being scheduled by the Carrier Threads (CT) and that by default the number of CTs is matched with the number of CPU cores.
Now let's assume I deploy my service to Kubernetes and it has a CPU request of 1 core. For the sake of this example let's also assume that the node it's being scheduled on has 8 cores. Because how Kubernetes allocates CPU my service will get 1/8 of the time of each CPU cores.
So here comes the question: how many CT should the service have for best utilization?

If the CPU limit of the pod is defined as 1 core it would automatically have 1 CT assigned to it which doesn't seem ideal as it will have 8 cores to run threads on
If it doesn't have a CPU limit set it would take the number of cores on the Node resulting 8 CTs.
as an intermediate solution I can remove CPU limit and define the visible CPU count which then gives a better control on the number of CTs.


Your process will get as much CPU time as it keeps busy, up to a maximum of 1 CPU-second per second.  It doesn't get allocated specific cores and it could potentially be doing work in parallel on multiple cores if there are multiple underlying OS threads.  If your application is either generally CPU-bound or makes rigorous use of asynchronous I/O (futures or a library like Reactor) then possibly one thread will be all it can use; if the application code has blocking I/O and needs regular thread switching then more than one might be right.

I think you're missing the point of my question, which is: what is the ideal setup for the number of CTs for a Java app running on a multi-core Kubernetes Node. The question obviously assumes that I have enough CPU intense task to keep the allocated CPU busy.

The JVM will pick a number of carrier threads for the number of available cores that is a good estimate. Special configuration should not be necessary.

@LouisWasserman As far I'm aware, Java will do that based on the CPU requests quota of Kubernetes. So if CPU requests is 1, it will configure itself as if you have 1 CPU, and you will need explicit configuration to override that (e.g. by setting the system property jdk.virtualThreadScheduler.parallelism on the java commandline).

You can probably also specify -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=8, but I'm not 100% sure that also influences the parallelism of the virtual thread scheduler or not.

@LouisWasserman it's not that simple in kubernetes though, hence my question for the ideal setup

@MarkRotteveel Java sees number of cores based on the CPU limit, or if it's not defined it would see all cores of the given node. Again, the question is what's the ideal configuration and not really the command to achieve it.

@Balazs That is why I posted comments, not an answer. In any case, there is no "ideal setup", it depends on your workload, and possibly workload of other pods on your node. Generally, I would expect no problem if you would set -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=8 (i.e. the same as the actual number of cores), in some cases it might be better to reduce it, for example if your pod gets throttled a lot.

@MarkRotteveel workload of other pods on the node is quite irrelevant as there is no "noisy neighbour" thing in kubernetes. Ofc there is no "one solution for all", my point with this question is to get best practices from people who know enough of Kubernetes and about Virtual threads.

@Balazs If you get throttled a lot, it might be better for the responsiveness of your application to reduce the CPU time it needs, which might be done by reducing the total number of threads performing work. And if all your pods are CPU intensive, and have a lot of threads competing for CPU time, that will decrease efficiency, and again reducing the threads might alleviate that.

The idea that pods can not be a noisy neighbour is nice in theory, but in the end, all work is done on the same set of CPUs, and more threads is more context switching, is more overhead.

@MarkRotteveel If your pod is within its CPU request (which it should be) then the above is not really true though. But this is a different and probably much longer conversation
